# how to debug a package dependent on multiple packages?

Tags: ros, navigation, gdb, move-base, motion-planners

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,
I am trying a global planner based on D* lite. I am using launch files in sbpl_lattice_planner. But move_base dies as soon as goal is passed through nav_view!
The problem is how to run this complete setup in gdb as there are multiple executables involved and roslaunch do a lot of things. Parameters can be set using rosparam, but
**How I can run a node in some namespace in gdb ?**

The part of  launch file look like this:

thanks
prince

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10855/how-to-debug-a-package-dependent-on-multiple-packages?/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2011-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure about the namespace thing, but to launch a node in gdb you usually add the launch-prefix attribute to the node tag like this:

```
<node launch-prefix="gdb -ex run --args" .../>
```

Did you try that already?

See also [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB)

---

Originally posted by [LiMuBei](https://answers.ros.org/users/68/limubei/) with karma: 261 on 2011-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2